# What is the most efficient way to transfer few props from a component to its child in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Either i should concatenate all the data i want to transfer into a single object and send it as a single prop or transfer each of them separately as a separate props?

let's suppose, i have 10 props:

2 small json arrays,

5 integers

3 strings.

In child component i will use it in some functions to render proper data.
I will have from 50 to 1000 child components like this

Comment: Can you provide more context? Why ten props? How are they used?

Comment: I've added aditional info

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way (the cleanest way) in this case would be to use [spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes). There is no difference in efficiency.

```js
var props = {};
props.foo = x;
props.bar = y;
var component = <Component {...props} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var data = {
             array1: this.props.array1,
             array2: this.props.array2,
             interger1: this.props.int1,
             etc etc..
        }
        return (
            <component2 data={data} />
        )
    }
})
```